# Update MAMP phpmyadmin 4.0.4

Tags: mamp

So phpMyAdmin 4.0.4 is out now it has the new cool jQuery style and the http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html only comes with the outdated phpMyAdmin 3.5.1.

Is there way to update? I've tried for the last hour and there is not a lot of resources out there for keeping phpMyAdmin on MAMP updated.

I tried downloading the phpMyAdmin 4.0.4 and replacing that folder content with what's inside the Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/ contents. and get all sorts of errors. is there a one click install to update this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have MAMP Pro -

1. Download latest version of phpMyAdmin (will probably be named something like phpMyAdmin-x.x.x-allLanguages, etc)
2. Save the folder to your desktop or downloads folder (somewhere you'll find it easily)
3. Make sure MAMP servers are off
4. In Finder, go into your existing phpMyAdmin directory (usually located in Applications/MAMP/bin/
5. **Copy** the 'config.inc.php' file from that existing phpMyAdmin directory.
6. Paste that config.inc.php into the directory of the latest version you just downloaded.
7. Back in /MAMP/bin - rename the existing / old phpMyAdmin folder to 'phpMyAdmin-old' or something similar (just in case there are issues you can go back)
8. **Copy** the latest version directory (the one you just downloaded and pasted the config.inc.php file into) and place it into the /MAMP/bin directory.
9. Rename the new directory to 'phpMyAdmin'

I just did this in August 2017 and it works 100%.

Answer (score 0):

**How to upgrade phpMyAdmin in MAMP / MAMP PRO**

1. [Download the latest version](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)
2. Unpack the archive you just downloaded, the resulting folder should be called somewhat like "phpMyAdmin-x.y-all-languages"
3. Copy (in the Finder press ALT key to copy the file) the file "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php" to "phpMyAdmin-x.y-all-languages"
4. Rename "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/phpMyAdmin" to "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/phpMyAdmin-OLD"
5. Rename "/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin" to "/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin-OLD"
6. Copy "phpMyAdmin-x.y-all-languages" to "/Applications/MAMP/bin/"
7. Rename "/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin-x.y-all-languages" to "/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin"
8. Copy "phpMyAdmin-x.y-all-languages" to "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/"
9. Rename "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/phpMyAdmin-x.y-all-languages" to "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/phpMyAdmin"

**Attention: Do not simply move files or folders, copy them.**

Source: http://blog-en.mamp.info/2013/08/how-to-upgrade-phpmyadmin-in-mamp-mamp.html